# 391 ceramic capacitor is not turning on my LED using 3.5 V power

Tags: capacitor

A very beginner Question.
I have attached a 5mm LED to 3.5 V power coming out if my aurduino port. 
Light turns on its own however, when I put a `391 ceramic capacitor (390 pf)` in the middle nothing happens. Did I burn the capacitor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgt6Ru.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to see the LED blink.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please add a simple schematic of how you have wired this because it sounds like you have wired a capacitor in series with the LED and this won't work. There is a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar. Please edit your question to explain why you have added the capacitor and what you think it is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the schematic. Why do you think adding a capacitor will make the LED blink? Your present schematic has only one end of the LED connected to the circuit so even if the rest of it worked the LED wouldn't light as no current can flow through it.

Comment: I thought capacitors are supposed to hold power and release it quickly like a battery

Comment: They can in certain configurations but you are a long way from understanding how to use them like that. Start with some circuit basics. Power the LED from 5 V using a resistor to limit the current to a safe value for the LED. See a couple of articles I wrote on [Battery and LED without a resistor](https://lednique.com/battery-plus-led-without-resistor/) and [Ohm's law and resistor calculation](https://lednique.com/electrical-theory-basics/ohms-law-and-resistor-calculation/) for some basic information on this.

Comment: Schematics are intended to logically show the whole equivalent circuit and yours does not.  Cables can be inductive antenna, and stray EMI noise can make LEDs glow.  What you saw is not in the schematic well enough to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I would suggest first learning what a capacitor is, and how it works. See this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359481/understanding-a-circuit-with-a-capacitor

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting 5 volts, not 3.5 volts, from a USB port.  Also, you should have a current-limiting resistor in series with the LED.

Now, to answer your question: A capacitor is an open circuit for DC, so if you connect one in series with your LED, no current will flow, and the LED will not light.  (Actually, a small current will flow very briefly - with that capacitor, the current pulse will be so short that you won't detect any light.)

I assume the capacitor is marked "391" - that is a code to indicate 390 pF.

This sort of code is commonly used in electronics for marking resistors and capacitors, but you should use the actual value when describing the component.  The first two digits give the first two digits of the value, and the third digit gives the number of zeros to add to get the value.  For capacitors, the value is in picofarads, for resistors it is in Ohms.

Comment: Sorry I am using my Aurduino port. I updated my diagram. I have tried a resistor (which just dims the light). isn't a capacitor supposed to store and release electricity? it's a 391 ceramic capacitor by the way

Comment: @Josepha just to add to this, the practical upshot of this DC blocking/ AC passing property is that you can use a capacitor to separate the DC portion of an AC signal.

Comment: I often describe a capacitor as a (very small) rechargeable battery - if the applied voltage is higher than the capacitor's voltage, it will accept charge until the voltages are equal.  If the applied voltage is less than the capacitor's voltage, it will discharge until the voltages are equal.  In either case, the capacitor attempts to keep the voltage across itself constant.  It does not charge to some point, then suddenly release all its charge to the external circuit.

Answer (score 0):

DC don't go through cap's. Ac will go through caps. I think you need a resistor instead of cap.

Comment: Based on the OP’s schematic, swapping the capacitor for a resistor won’t help. Also, while I understand the intention of your answer, your statements are not quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

When an LED diode rectifies some low-level current it glows.

If it was caused by some RF signal that disappears with a cap, then we suspect the stray noise is being bypassed or shunted thru the small capacitor.

If was created by a DC voltage with a series resistance to ground =" 0V return" then we have created a DC current loop to turn on the light.

These are 2 different scenarios and it is not clear which applies to you.

If you attached only one end of a diode to a USB cable and it started to glow there must stray Electric field and high impedance coupling capacitance somewhere like thru your finger and body to conduct enough return current in hundreds of microamps to glow.

This can be caused by long cables, stray electric field noise and our bodies acting as capacitors to pass very low current to a cable. The USB host may have an isolated power supply but also some coupling capacitance to the AC lines with some high switching frequency.

The actual physical layout of your test and proximity to an earth bonded ground and AC line high impedance electric fields can affect un-terminated components and signal ports. It also makes them very susceptible to damage from ESD being high impedance and not connected to a low impedance driver.

Small ceramic capacitors only conduct current according to Ic(f)=V * C * 2pi * f  and here C = 390 pF or 0.000000000390 Farads  pico = 1e-12

They dont burn out that easily since they dont conduct much current except when V*f are much greater than C.

So they are low impedance for AM radio (1MHz) but relatively high Giga ohms for 50/60 Hz